# How to transform a line string in float numbers Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string line like this way:

```
f=open(flowsrc.baseflowpath+flowsrc.baseflowfile,"r")
lines=f.readlines()[1:] #jump the first line
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split(' ')[0])
f.close()
print x, type(x)

out: 19     0       1.8881      .4928
out: <type 'str'>
```

How can I put the elements of `x` in array in float format? like this:

```
a = [19.0]
b = [0.0]
c = [1.8881]
d = [0.4928]
```

Comment: Could you attach input data example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example `str` from your question `x = '19     0       1.8881      .4928'`, you can use the following comprehension to unpack each value as a `float` into a `list` (`nums`) for processing as required.

```
nums = [ float(i) for i in x.split(' ') if i != '' ]
```

If you want to unpack each value to its own list as outlined in your question:

```py
a = [nums[0]]
b = [nums[1]]
c = [nums[2]]
d = [nums[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line from:

```
result.append(x.split(' ')[0])
```

to:

```
result.append(float(x.split(' ')[0]))
```

Comment: Didn't work:  `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`